Update mutation in appysnc takes time to render recent changes, even dynamo db is already updated
I have an app which has a WYSWIG inside it I used debounce and on stop typing listener to save my content after the user stops typing. But it seems if the user reloads the page after the save even if it reflected in dynamo db the response from the query still returns the old values for some reason and it's becoming a raise condition bug I cannot fix.

Might be due to the lag in GSI.

Was due to one of the collaborators enabled caching without letting us know which gets a little delay.
